# Submit form if any Ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, error-handling

How can I make ajax/jquery submit the form in case of ANY ajax error?

I want the regular submit pageload php validation to take over, in case of any ajax error

If I try and replace 'validateform.php' with 'xxxxtest.nothing', the form does not submit, and js throws console error "POST http://example.com/xxxxtest.nothing 404 (Not Found)"

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {

    var $theform = $(this);

    $.ajax({
    url: 'validateform.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    async: false,
    data: $theform.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        $('#errordiv').html('<p class="error">' + data + '</p>');
        $('#errordiv').slideDown();
    },
    error: function(e){
        return true; // form should be submitted
    }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: jQuery ajax function is asynchronous, so `return false` is always exectuted.

Comment: @martynas Result: Freeze + endless loop of "POST http://example.com/xxxxtest.nothing 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles So what should I do?

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.

Comment: Removing async false made the page not freeze on clicking submit button. But still loop of "POST example.com/xxxxtest.nothing 404 (Not Found)" in console (and no submit of form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ajax function is asynchronous, so return false is always exectuted. So, instead:

```
error: function(e){
    $('#myform').unbind('submit').submit();
}
```

Updated based on comments below.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Q2L2/

Comment: Result: No submitting + endless loop of "POST example.com/xxxxtest.nothing 404 (Not Found)" in console

Comment: Getting closer ;) But now it seems to just reload the page, not submit the form

Comment: Run the ajax again to replace the normal submit

Comment: @IagoMelanias Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: That submits the form just fine at the posted JSFiddle. Have the console open and look for the failed GET.

Comment: It does not submit the form. It just reloads somehow

Comment: On the JSFiddle? Or your form. What is the "action" attribute set to?

Comment: It's "add.php" (same page). And in that I check the form with php. Nothing wrong in that page. But using $('#myform').unbind('submit').submit(); it just opens add.php and does not submit it. Php gets nothing to work on. If I remove all JS, add.php submits fine and php outputs form validation

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` at the top of add.php output? Post your form HTML in question to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Ah! Error found.. I was using this in php to check if the form is submitted (it checks the button and not the form itself!): (isset($_POST['upd_submit']) && !empty($_POST['upd_submit'])) {

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works to you:
http://jsfiddle.net/don/9Q2L2/3/

Create a second php file to send the form and run this php file if any ajax error.

Use the `unbind` and the `submit` again.

Comment: So, if Ajax fails: run another ajax (even one without ajax error checking)? That does not seem like the best practice

Comment: Well. You could use only one file e get your response using just php. Check validation based on the file response using ajax isn't a good practice too.

Comment: I check the form using a php validation page (but showing nice error presentation with jquery). And if ajax fails (or user has js disabled), it should just submit the form and continue regular php validation (same file).. I'm so close now.. just need the form to submit on ajax error

Comment: The php should do exactly this, without use the ajax response. If the validation is ok, send the form, if not, show the message error. And it's easier than manipulate the result based on the ajax response.

Answer (score -1):

You should try:

```
$('#myform').submit(function (event) {

    var $theform = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'validateform.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        async: false,
        data: $theform.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#errordiv').html('<p class="error">' + data + '</p>');
            $('#errordiv').slideDown();
            //prevent submit
            event.preventDefault();

        },
        error: function (event) {
            //form is submitted

        }
    });

    //None of them should be placed here, the code is always executed
    //event.preventDefault();
    //return false;

});
```

[More about preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: Now the form gets submitted no matter what

Comment: Are you sure that the AJAX call is accessible?